# What is the negation of this statement with two for alls?

Tags: logic

What is the negation of $\forall x \; \forall y P(x) \wedge Q(y)$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(y)$ are logical statements about x and y. Is it $\exists x \; \exists y \;!P(x) \vee\; !Q(y)$? Where ! is the not operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. We know that $\lnot\forall xP(x)=\exists x\lnot P(x)$ so if we apply that to your statement we get $$\begin{align}\lnot\forall x~\forall y~(P(x)\land Q(y)&=\exists x~\lnot\forall y~(P(x)\land Q(y))\\&=\exists x~\exists y~\lnot(P(x)\land Q(y))\\&=\exists x~\exists y~(\lnot P(x)\lor\lnot Q(y))\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The negation of $$\forall x \; \forall y P(x) \wedge Q(y)$$

is $$ \exists x \exists y ( \lnot P(x) \lor \lnot Q(y))   $$